# Python wrappers - Confusion about variable scope

Tags: python, wrapper, scope

I thought I would be clever and write a wrapper that called the session variables (many are present) and add that to the (django) views requiring session variables.  However I seem to not be understanding the scope of the variables, or am writing this incorrectly.

The wrapper I have is:

```
def s_vars(func_to_decorate):
    @wraps(func_to_decorate)
    def wrapper(request, *args, **kwargs):
        #add all the session variables to kwargs and accessible for the decorated function.
        user_obj = request.user
        datepicker = request.session['datepicker']
        date_format = request.session['date_format']
        .........
        country = request.session['country']
        metric = request.session['metric']
        qrydtm = request.session.get("qrydtm",date.today())

        result = func_to_decorate(request, *args, **kwargs)

        #any post view checks to be done go here

        #return to the function to be decorated.
        return result
    return wrapper
```

Then for the view I have something like:

```
@s_vars
def main(request, template_name='placeholder.html'):
    return render_to_response(template_name, RequestContext(request,{
           'user':user_obj
            }))
```

But this leads to the error that user_obj is not accessible inside the method "main".  My understanding was that this is an inner function and therefore the variables in the list under the "wrapper" method would be accessible to this inner function "main".  What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax

```
@spam
def ham():
    pass
```

is precisely equivalent to the syntax

```
def ham():
    pass
ham = spam(ham)
```

Does that clarify why what you are doing doesn't work?

---

If you want to pass stuffto a function from a decorator, the usual idiom is to send extra arguments to the function. This can be a little icky, because it means that the argspec that *looks* right is actually not.

Answer (score 0):

Nested functions *only* take scoped variables from the scope where they are defined, and the binding takes place at compile time.

You cannot add scoped variables later on, and certainly not with a simple wrapper.

Answer (score 0):

At the point where the inner function is **called**, it is just called by the outer scope function, not **defined** in it.

That distinction (also made by interpreter vs runtime) is definitely important in scoping.  Take a look at the dis (disassembly) of the s_vars wrapper (or a reduced simple example of the same behaviour). The code is not reinterpreted for different values (it is just a value here) of `func_to_decorate`.

If you want to make a list of variables available to the inner function, perhaps an object passed in would make more sense. The wrapper could ensure that the external API is without it.